# TSQL 2012 deleted table in INSTEAD OF and AFTER triggers?

Tags: sql-server-2012, trigger

My colleague ask me very simple, but difficult for me question:

If I have `deleted` table with 10 records in `INSTEAD OF` trigger and I delete 8 of them how many records will I have in `deleted` table in `AFTER` trigger?

I think it wuold be 10, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very easy to test.

```
CREATE TABLE T(X INT);

GO

INSERT INTO T 
SELECT TOP 10 1
FROM sys.all_objects;

GO

CREATE TRIGGER TR1 ON T INSTEAD OF DELETE AS DELETE TOP (8) FROM T;

GO

CREATE TRIGGER TR2 ON T AFTER DELETE AS SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DELETED;

GO

DELETE FROM T;


DROP TABLE T;
```

> Answer **8**

This is the correct behaviour. The after trigger should reflect the rows that were actually deleted. If you had an audit trigger recording 10 deletions when only 8 occurred this would be clearly incorrect.

Comment: Ok, I know that I can easily test. I rather preffer why it is 8? I suppose that AFTER is based on real deleted rows, but I am not sure. May be I did not ask properly. 10x anyway for quick and simple response.